# Release версия проекта в Visual Studio 2008 работает не правильно. Почему?

Tags: visual-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой. Когда проверяю прогу на работоспособность в Debug версии, всё работает как задумывалось. Как только собираю проект в Release версии и запускаю, появляются разные глюки, которых не было. Программу плющит не подетски. Почему это происходит и как это исправить? Это проблема компилятора?

Comment: В моём случае оказалась проблема с памятью. Строки слишком большие, вылазят за пределы. Но это в этом проекте. В другом математика страдала. Там скорее всего из-за потоков проблемы были.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По опыту, основная причина ошибок, проявляющихся только в Release-версии, связана с работой с динамической памятью. Запустите программу в Debug-версии в отладчике и *внимательно* посмотрите на сообщения, в частности, на предупреждения - не "утекает" ли у Вас память? Ведь очень многие компиляторы "оборачивают", например, операторы `new`/`delete` в отладочной версии.

Вторая часть ошибок обычно связана с многопоточностью. Отладочная информация (да еще и подсоединенный отладчик) несколько замедляют работу программы, причем как-то удивительно по-разному для разных потоков(нитей), и поэтому взаимоблокировки, например, в отладочной версии не проявляются.

Еще одна подсказка - попробуйте собрать версию "Release без оптимизации". Т.е. все опции как в Debug'е, но без собственно отладочной информации. Посмотрите, что изменится. И наконец, соберите еще один вариант, "Debug с оптимизацией как в Release", и запустите и без отладчика и в отладчике. Такие нехитрые приемы в свое время мне очень помогали.

Успехов!

Comment: Это, кстати, наиболее вероятно.

Answer (score 1):

Еще одна возможная причина: какие-то переменные не инициализированы в релизе. Дебаг пишет нули, релиз - мусор.

Comment: Не.. я точно все переменные проинициализировал

Answer (score 0):

В релизной версии может быть иная логика работы, чем в отладочной как минимум из-за

- оптимизирующей компиляции,
- меньшей реактивности,
- отсутствия отладочного кода.

Проверить в чем причина можно обычными методами отладки:

- попробовать разные опции компиляции,
- попробовать вставлять задержки,
- добавить отладочные печати.

И кроме того, вполне возможно, что проектные установки для Release и Debug отличаются в чем-то существенном: не та библиотека линкуется в Release, что в Debug и т.п.

Comment: Скорее всего, ошибка в коде. Есть достаточно широкий класс ошибок, ведущих себя подобным образом .-. Причём, может быть и наоборот - в дебуге всё плохо, а в релизе работает. Правда, большая часть этих ошибок связана с 64-битными программами, незнанием и неправильным использованием типов. Но не тоолько.

Answer (score 0):

Видел пример когда изменение переменной, находящейся в критической секции, выносилось за ее пределы. Можно попробовать все переменные, к которым имеют доступ несколько потоков, как volatile.

UPD
нашел этот пример [тыц](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/04/volatile.html#comment-1976129473176086084)

Comment: Вообще многие concurrency проблемы могут выплыть в Release-сборке, не только проблемы с volatile

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с такими проблемами.

1. В одной программе я использовал трассировку стека. В дебаге всё было OK, в релизе нужный мне метод в стеке просто отсутствовал. Вылечилось пометкой метода атрибутом MethodImpl в опцией NoInlining
2. В различной конфигурации компилятор выдавал слегка разные значения какой-то математической функции, вроде бы синуса. При обработке больших наборов данных это накапливалось и было заметно.

Comment: т.е. без Inline функций?(1-я проблема)

Comment: Я явно отключил Inline в тех местах, где мне нужно было динамически получить имя метода через трассировку стека.<br><br>

Кстати, последняя версия нашей утилиты для обновления структуры БД как раз сейчас тоже работает только под отладчиком. На 64-битной системе установленная из собранного сегодня ночью дистрибутива версия падает, причём на таком низком уровне, что исключение даже до логов не доходит. Похоже, какие-то проблемы с опциями компиляции.

Comment: Да, мне тоже кажется это что-то с опциями. Но только в каких? Загадка... И как вы решили решили проблему?

Comment: Отключили anyCPU, всегда собираем приложение под x86. За сегодня один раз всё равно упало, но хотя бы не всё время. Говорят, новая версия используемой нами графической библиотеки работает более стабильно, надо бы перейти...